# Apache Ignite JDBC Thin Client Does not work with Existing Cache

Tags: ignite

I have created an Ignite cache "contact" and added "Person" object to it. 
When I use Ignite JDBC Client mode I am able to query this cache. But when I implement JDBC Thin Client, it says that the table Person does not exist. 
I tried the query this way:

```
Select * from Person

Select * from contact.Person
```

Both did not work with Thin Client. I am using Ignite 2.1.
I appreciate your help as how to query an existing cache using Thin Client.
Thank you.

**Cache Configuration in default-config.xml**

```
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite Persistent Store. -->
    <property name="persistentStoreConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.PersistentStoreConfiguration"/>
        </property>

        <property name="binaryConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.BinaryConfiguration">
                <property name="compactFooter" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="memoryConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.MemoryConfiguration">
                <!-- Setting the page size to 4 KB -->
                <property name="pageSize" value="#{4 * 1024}"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide a list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                <value>127.0.0.1:55500..55502</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Cache Configuration in the Server Side of the Code**

```
CacheConfiguration<Long, Person> cc = new CacheConfiguration<>(cacheName);            
    cc.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
    cc.setRebalanceMode(CacheRebalanceMode.ASYNC);
    cc.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, Person.class);
    cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cc);
```

**Thin Client JDBC URL**

```
 Class.forName("org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver");
            // Open the JDBC connection.
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ignite:thin://192.168.1.111:10800");

            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
```

Comment: Could you share your cache configuration and jdbc connection string?

Comment: Denis, please see the cache configuration and JDBC URL. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Denis, do you have any solution that you recommend for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to query data from an existing cache using SQL, you should specify an SQL schema in the cache configuration. Add the following code before the cache creation:

```java
cc.setSqlSchema("PUBLIC");
```

Note that you have persistence configured, so when you do `ignite.getOrCreateCache(cc);` the new configuration won't be applied, if a cache with this name is already persisted. You should, for example, remove persistence data or use `createCache(...)` method instead.

Comment: Denis, this makes a perfect sense. I will try to set the sqlSchema to Public and see. Thank you so much for your quick answer.